# Limit Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, html-select

I am trying to have a thumbnail gallery which is selectable by the user. The user can choose if the image is a "header" or "logo" but can only pick one image as header and one as logo. I am not quite sure how to do this. Would this require some javascript?

Here is my loop (this will be getting images from a folder in the future)

Thanks

```
<?php

echo "<div style='width: 1125px; overflow:scroll; height:400px;'>";

for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++)
{

echo " <div class='image' style='width:200px; float:left;'>
      <div class='photo' style='width:200px;'>
        <img src='images/logo.jpg' width='25%'>
      </div>

      <select name='4365'>
        <option value='NONE'></option>
        <option value='PRIMARY'>Primary</option>
        <option value='LOGO'>Logo</option>
      </select><br><br>
    </div>";    
}

echo "</div>";

echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";

?>
```

Comment: you have to use some javascript to check if the selected option is valid for you. `<select name='4365' multiple>` allows multiple options to be selected. there are actually a handful ways how to do this. Maybe you should read up about this and try it yourself. ask again if you got specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a select on each image, you could have two radio buttons; one with name "primary", the other with name "logo", and the value would be the image id. That way, the user could select only one primary and only one logo across all of the images presented.